# Resolved [org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, orm

```java
    package com.codedecode.demo.entity;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

    import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
    import lombok.Getter;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.Setter;
    import lombok.ToString;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, length = 100)
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<CV> cv;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<JobApplication> jobApplication;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<CurriculumVitae> curriculumVitae;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<CoverLetter> coverLetter;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Address address;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "career_goals")
    private String careerGoals;

    @Column(name = "university")
    private String university;

    @Column(name = "rating")
    private String rating;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Notification> notifications;

    @Column(name = "maria_status")
    private String mariaStatus;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Degree> degrees;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Posting> postings;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Language> languages;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Experience> experiences;

    @Column(name = "taxt_number")
    private Long taxtNumber;

    @Column(name = "images")
    private String images;

    @Column(name = "candidate_cv")
    private String candidateCV;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "desired_job_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private DesiredJob desiredJob;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "candidate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Message> candidateMessage;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recruiter", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Message> recruiterMessage;
    
//  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
//  @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_profile_save_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private CandidateProfileSaved candidateProfileSaved;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<SavedJob> savedJob;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<AppliedJob> appliedJob;

    public User(Long id, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("User [id=");
        builder.append(id);
        builder.append(", email=");
        builder.append(email);
        builder.append(", address=");
        builder.append(address);
        builder.append(", password=");
        builder.append(password);
        builder.append(", name=");
        builder.append(name);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    }
```

[image: orm generate users table]

I don't know why when I try to insert more users to database from postman call api then I have an error is : "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_hbvhqvjgmhd5omxyo67ynvbyp'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.users'. The duplicate key value is (1)."

Why primary key of users is not increment ?

Comment: Please share code and scripts as text formatted as code, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

Table already have identity in its id column. So, maybe, Hiberante must be enabling IDENTITY_INSERT option and trying reinsert de row.

Comment: Can you give a soulution on spring boot ?

Comment: Can you run sp_help users and show the constraints on thsi table?

Comment: Thanks but I found the way to fix and error come from mssql

Comment: How you solved?

Comment: create database [DATABASE_NAME] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8;

Answer (score 0):

```
create database [DATABASE_NAME] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8;
```

Comment: How does that solve the problem with a unique constraint violation of the ID?